# SwiftUI NavigationLink how to get to another SwiftUI page?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to get from one SwiftUI view to another SwiftUI view and I'm using a NavigationLink as per the code below, but I'm getting the error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NavigationLink<_, _>' with an argument list of type '(destination: PlaylistTable)'

Below is my code for the button which triggers the link to the next view:

```
struct MusicButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        Button(action: {
            NavigationLink(destination: PlaylistTable())
        })
        { Image(systemName: "music.note.list")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .font(Font.title.weight(.ultraLight))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `NavigationLink` inside a `Button` will solve your problem:

```
 NavigationView {

        NavigationLink(destination: PlaylistTable())
    { Image(systemName: "music.note.list")
        .resizable()
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .font(Font.title.weight(.ultraLight))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the button, then move the navigation link to the background.

```
struct MusicButton: View {

    @State var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        Button(action: {
            isActive.toggle()
        })
        { Image(systemName: "music.note.list")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .font(Font.title.weight(.ultraLight))
            }
        }
        .background(
             NavigationLink(destination: PlaylistTable(), isActive: $isActive) {EmptyView()}
         )
    }
}
```